# Allow cyclic connections in custom node tree

Tags: python, scripting, pynodes

I want to allow a cyclic connection in a custom node tree.
Here is an example screenshot of a cyclic connection.
[image: Invalid Link in a cycle]

From what I uderstand, the following happens:
As soon as a link is inserted such that a cycle is closed, blender will mark one link within the cycle as invalid, which is being drawn red.
Is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: A node network like that can be very confusing, hard to see where something begins and ends and what triggers what. I see you are after a flow-chart type network with returns and go-toes, but they use arrows and different node shapes and so are much visually clearer. The way to approach this in nodal networks is to have subtrees with clear start-end flow that can be run multiple times or in loop from other nodes. By the design these subtrees cannot interfere with each other, unlike cyclic connections where you can create a huge mess. Go-to statements in a regular code should be minimal too.

Comment: I'm modeling a variation of petri net structure - I don't see how this would work with subtrees in my case.

Comment: Then imho your only option is to draw custom nodes with [bgl module](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bgl.html?highlight=bgl), handle linking them and write an engine to execute/simulate them. If it's possible you can also convert that petri net to state machine and generate blender nodes for that.

Comment: I don't really need to simulate/execute the model within Blender, since I am exporting this petrinet-like node structure, and primarily use it somewhere else. In blender Its just data, that belongs to the model file.
If i use bgl, I will technically have to reimplement the whole node editor - that seems like maybe too much work for what i have in mind .... maybe i can work with the invalid link after all and just export that - the red link mostly looks ugly.

Comment: You can turn the red link off if you set the [is_valid flag](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeLink.html?highlight=is_valid%20link#bpy.types.NodeLink.is_valid) to `True` for each link, you will have to do that after every time the node links get updated by Blender.